# Qml images and memory releasing

Tags: image, qt, memory, qml, qt-quick

I noticed that memory allocated for Image is not released.

Without launched app the system has the following memory values: 423MiB /  1985MiB (checked via nvidia-smi)

When I am launching app and clicking (changing Image source) several times the memory using is increasing (1 click adds 4-5MB): 1950MiB /  1985MiB

Setting "cache" property to false does not help.

I found workaround: change image visibility but in this case a lot Image items are needed.

Does a solution exist to use "source" property not "visible"?

qml source:

```
Image {
    id: trg
    anchors.fill: parent
    cache: false

    states: [
        State {
            name: "on"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: trg
                source: "qrc:/1.png"
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "off"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: trg
                source: "qrc:/2.png"
            }
        }
    ]
}

MouseArea {
    property bool isOn: false
    anchors.fill: parent

    onClicked: {
        if (isOn) {
            trg.state = "on";
        }
        else {
            trg.state = "off";
        }
        isOn = !isOn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, caching system/gs sucks in QML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it was a bug ([QTBUG-61754](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61754) and a few more) which has already been fixed in the qt 5.9.2 snapshot (I used to use 5.9.1 version).